# Using Spring Security Without Cookies

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, security

I need to implement session management in a Spring app for a mobile browser that doesn't support cookies.  Can this be done by putting the session id in the querystring of a GET request?  How do you manage this with Spring? Is there a built-in option I'm missing?  Should I write my own auth filter?  Are there special security issues to consider with this approach?

We're running Spring 2.0.6, so I'd be using Spring Security 2.

Answer (score 1):

try using `<http disable-url-rewriting="false">`. This will append session id to the URL.